# WooCommerce woe_get_order_value_cancel-date hooked function issue

Tags: php, woocommerce

In the wp_postmeta table I have a meta-key called 'cancel-date' with a meta-value of July 5, 2020. I am am using an export to CSV tool and trying to export these values but with a different format using the filter below but it is not working for me. I would like to export it to look like YYYYMMDD.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
add_filter('woe_get_order_value_cancel-date',function ($value, $order,$fieldname) {

$value = date('Ymd', strtotime($value));
return $value;
},10,3);
```

Comment: Sorry but your question/answer is unclear as the hook `woe_get_order_value_cancel-date` is a custom hook that is not included in WooCommerce. Your issue is not testable or reproducible:
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers. So you should better delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, it turns out I had pre-defined the field as a 'date' field so it kept overwriting my formatting.